# Cannot addObject into a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have a question about the objective-C. I use the following code to add a contains from an array to another array. However, the second array is null. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
titleArray = [[csvDataArrayString objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSString *title;

dataTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  // after add this statement it's ok

for(int i=0; i<[tTitleArray count]; i++)
{
    title = [csvPersonalTitleArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [dataTitleArray addObject:title];  // the dataTitleArray is null
}
```

Comment: If dataTitleArray is nil, then you'll need to expand your question to show where you're creating dataTitleArray and how it comes to be in the snippet you've quoted.

Comment: Or all these lines of code actually next to each other in this order, as written here, or are you picking and choosing from different parts of your program? I suspect the latter, and if so, there's no way we're going to find the bug from random snippets.

Comment: @Jarret Hardie, Chuck, thank you for your reply. It's solved Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown that you're actually allocating `dataTitleArray` anywhere. Are you? It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I edited the post. I just want to add an array to another array.

Comment: `[oneArray addObjectsFromArray:anotherArray]`